# A shortcode nested inside a shortcode

Tags: shortcode

This is my first time asking a question here. I'm kinda stuck on how to do `echo do_shortcode();` inside a shortcode.

I tried googling for an answer but to no avail.

I'd like to know if it is possible to echo a shortcode inside a shortcode. If it is, any pointer is much appreciated.

Thank you.

```
    function cpa_haven_banner() {
        return '    
            <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal entry-meta">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-action-item">
                    <strong>Female</strong> <?php echo do_shortcode("[get_sheet_value location='LOAN!B7']"); ?>
                </li>
            </ul>
        ';
    }
    add_shortcode('cpa-haven', 'cpa_haven_banner');
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
function cpa_haven_banner() {
    
    $shortcode = do_shortcode("[get_sheet_value location='LOAN!B7']");
    
    return '    
            <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal entry-meta">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-action-item">
                    <strong>Female</strong> ' . $shortcode .
                '</li>
            </ul>
        ';
    }
add_shortcode('cpa-haven', 'cpa_haven_banner');
```

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate the help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would put all the markup in a variable, and return the result of passing that through `do_shortcode`:

```
function cpa_haven_banner() {
    $html = '
        <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal entry-meta">
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-action-item">
                <strong>Female</strong> [get_sheet_value location=\'LOAN!B7\']
            </li>
        </ul>
    ';


    return do_shortcode( $html );
}
add_shortcode('cpa-haven', 'cpa_haven_banner');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Nate. That works!

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept the answer if this answer solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I did accepted this answer but my reputation didn't allow me to do so.

Comment: @yansusanto Okay, no problem! Thanks!